# Boolean naming convention using just verb

Tags: naming-conventions

I'm normally following bool naming convention and prefix everything with a short verb, e.g.:

- IsAdmin
- IsOnline
- HasData
- etc.

However I'm not really sure what do to in my case. I'm primarily working with SQL Server and I need some boolean flags that are a bit trickier to me to name. For instance I've got ones that are named:

- Migrate
- Reload

These all are verbs and that's it, however they're just verbs, where in example above that short verb is just suffix. Is it okay to name these like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database will most likely store the result of these actions i.e. the result of a migration or a reload.

Hence you could create Boolean variables to indicate whether these actions have executed e.g. IsMigrated (or HasBeenMigrated) or IsReloaded (or HasBeenReloaded)